# how to the calculate the value of textboxs if one of the text boxes is empty?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I want to calculate the value of 3 textboxes. It is not mandatory to give input to all 3 textboxes if one textbox is empty it should calculate for the remaining two textboxes. I'm getting this error "Input string was not in a correct format" for the textboxes where i didn't give input.

And this is my code

```
 double total = 0;
        if (TextBox1.Text == null)
           TextBox1.Text = "0";
        if (TextBox2.Text== null)
           TextBox2.Text = "0";
        if (TextBox3.Text == null)
           TextBox3.Text = "0";
        total = int.Parse(TextBox1.Text) * 0.10;
        total = total + (int.Parse(TextBox2.Text) * 20);
        total = total + (int.Parse(TextBox2.Text) * 30);
        Lbl.Text = total.ToString();
```

Comment: try using `String.IsNullOrEmpty(TextBoxN.Text)` for null comparison.

Comment: Show us your inputs (TextBox values).

Comment: Also beware of culture settings

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of checking just for null the text box Text property may/can return an empty string. So what you need to do is use `string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace()` method.

Here is you code changed to use that:

```
double total = 0;
        if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(TextBox1.Text))
           TextBox1.Text = "0";
        if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(TextBox2.Text))
           TextBox2.Text = "0";
        if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(TextBox3.Text))
           TextBox3.Text = "0";
        total = int.Parse(TextBox1.Text) * 0.10;
        total = total + (int.Parse(TextBox2.Text) * 20);
        total = total + (int.Parse(TextBox2.Text) * 30);
        Lbl.Text = total.ToString();
```

But that code is still open for bugs. What if the user enters a string that cannot be converted to an int. To handle that you'll need to do something like this:

```
public static double CalcTotal() {
        double total = 0;
        var ints = ToInts(textBox1.Text, textBox2.Text, textBox3.Text);
        var coef = new[] { 0.10d, 20, 30 };
        for (int i = 0; i < ints.Length && i < coef.Length; i++) {
            total += ints[i] * coef[i];
        }
        return total;
    }

    public static int[] ToInts(params string[] args) {
        var res = new int[args.Length];
        int i = 0;
        foreach (var s in args) {
            int num = 0;
            int.TryParse(s, NumberStyles.None, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, out num);
            res[i++] = num;
        }
        return res;
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

Input be a string so you need to place validation or try below code

```
        double total = 0;
        total = TryConvert(TextBox1.Text) * 0.10;
        total = total + (TryConvert(TextBox2.Text) * 20);
        total = total + (TryConvert(TextBox2.Text) * 30);
        Lbl.Text = total.ToString();

    public int TryConvert(string s)
    {
        int i = 0;
        int.TryParse(s, out i);
        return i;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You should check if the text is empty (in addition to checking null values).

Eg,

```
string.IsNullOrEmpty(Textbox1.Text)
```

You may use TryParse while converting the values.

Eg,

```
int textBox1Value = 0; 
int.TryParse(text, out textBox1Value);
```

Answer (score 0):

You've also got TextBox2.Text twice by the way, I think you mean TextBox3.Text!  Since you are calculating a double, you might like to consider using `double.Parse` instead of `int.Parse`.

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
if (TextBox3.Text == null||TextBox3.Text == "")
           TextBox3.Text = "0";
```

textboxes are always "" and not null.

Comment: @sharanya from all the other answers you find this one to be the best one :D What happens if TextBox3.Text  == "aisiktir"

Comment: This is not the complete solution!

Comment: Haha :D actually i tried this before getting so many notification over here and got the output so , when i found the similar method in this answer i marked it right @mcl

Comment: @virusivv "textboxes are always "" and not null."  so why are you comparing with null ?

Comment: @sharanya I see :) just a friendly advice when you write code and see a lot of lines that look almost the same but just use different variables try to come up with a solution that uses loops and arrays instead. That way the code will be easier to maintain and more error prone. Just to prove that look at your code and see  total = total + (int.Parse(TextBox2.Text) * 30); you use TextBox2 twice one time for *20 and one for *30. Is that what you  actually intended or is that just an error from copy/paste ;)

Comment: I copied the above code forgot to change the textbox value :/ @mcl